# how to get values from one page back to the previous page without any button click using jquery or ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I  have an excelsheet with rates, using a dropdown when i select a country the corresponding rate should be get and after that i need to divide the obtained value using the number which I select.For this I have been using two pages ,let it be first.php and second.php.The divident is selected from first.php and the operation of selecting the rate is performed in second.php.The obtained result is passed to first.php.
Problem is that i am able to get the rate printed but not able to perform division on it with first.php.the output shown is NAN.
I have been using ajax for this.

Comment: Many of the questions araised I have also when saw your question. Where is your code? What you have tried so far?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8uKIg-gAsOeRzlUUzBoeUd0VGs

Answer (score -1):

You access an undefined object. Show your code and possibly we can help.

Comment: And in which file and line is your calculation you talk about?